# Segmentation fault in qemu arm ubuntu disk image?

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, arm, qemu

I am using Ubuntu disk image for ARM architecture in Qemu. I compile several multi-threaded C-language programs and do little test to execute them. But for one of the programs, it has been failing with segmentation fault error most of the times. I have tried to trace the problematic area by putting printf statements. To my observation it crashes (somewhere inside the function being called by the function being passed to the threads) at different places mostly which makes it really difficult to determine about what went wrong and where was that?

The same program works fine, no matter how many times i execute it, using my Ubuntu x86 hardware machine.

Did anybody face a similar problem? Does this problem occur because of Qemu or Disk image or both?

Any help?

Comment: It may be worth using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on the native version to track down bad behaviour (even though it manages to not crash), before going to the effort of cross-debugging.

Comment: @Notlikethat Well, it produces a 98kB sized file, now idea, what to trace? apology for my ignorance...

Answer (score 0):

Just because a program runs in one environment is no guarantee that it doesn't have bugs.  Print statements are one method to find problems, but somewhat hit-or-miss.  Better is to use a real debugger.  You may need to have gdb server and a network port to debug the program running inside qemu, but that would let you set breakpoints, single step, examine variables, and get stack traces of your crash.

Comment: I have this disk image mounted and I do `sudo chroot .`.There is no gdb insdie the image. Could you suggest how to get gdb here or what else could be done?

Comment: Cross compile gdb & gdbserver. NFS mount and and copy.

Comment: Actaually, you only need to cross-compile gdbserver.  Connect to it with gdb running on the host.